# Does Install4j add-on installer have a manifest of new files

Tags: install4j

I am using the add-on configuration of install4j for updates to my product.  In some cases, I need to do special processing of certain files, for example to carry user-configured paramaters from the previous version into the new version.  Is there a way I can check if any of these certain files are present in the update (so I can have install4j run a script to save them before the new ones get installed, and then run another script to modify the new file afterwards)?

I suppose I can generate a Manifest, but this would be redundant since install4j already knows the information.  Conversely, it would be impractical to pre-save all the files a user could modify.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of install4j 5.1, there is no API to access the list of installed files. However the "Install files" action has a "File filter" property where each file is passed to as it is installed. You can build a list in an installer variable there and use it later on in a "Run script" action.

Comment: Ingo, while this is a great feature, I really need to know what files are going to be replaced so I can save them for later processing.  Thanks!

Comment: You could save them in the filter script. It is executed before the file is replaced.